# How can i increase Material UI overall animation speed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can i increase the overall animation speed of `Material UI`, for example there is a `drawer` component inside the `material UI`, and it can be opened or closed, how can i increase that animation speed ?
Even better how can i increase all the animation speeds in the `material UI`?

Comment: you can override the component using MUITheme or you can override the css.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Local overwriting

You can change transition duration for `<Drawer>` by adding `transitionDuration` prop to component.

```
<Drawer transitionDuration={1000}>  // time for entering and leaving in ms
```

If you want different time for entering and leaving then:

```
<Drawer transitionDuration={{ enter: 500, exit: 1000 }}>
```

[Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/drawer/)

Live demo:

[image: Edit Material demo]

#### Global overwriting (MUI 5)

As for global overwriting. You can use `<ThemeProvider>` and `createTheme` to inject your custom theme to application. Then you can overwrite many things, one of them is animation duration:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
    transitions: {
        duration: {
            enteringScreen: 2000,
            leavingScreen: 100,
        }
    }
});

function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <RestOfYourApp />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Live demo

[image: Edit Drawer-test]

#### Global overwriting (Material-UI <= 4.x)

Unfortunately it does not work in Material-UI version 4 (and older)

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    transitions: {
        duration: {
            enteringScreen: 2000,
            leavingScreen: 100,
        }
    }
}); 

function App() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <RestOfYourApp />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

It works... for some components, for example `<Button>`. But other (like `<Drawer>`) has transition properties [hardcoded in source code](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/9fb11b6f487d012fadc880c3e9fcd636a4aa3a88/packages/material-ui/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L100/material-ui/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L99).

So, only way to change `<Drawer>` transition duration in Material-UI 4, is adding `transitionDuration` prop to component.

Comment: This is an issue for some other MUI components as well, such as the Transition components (Slide, Fade etc); they also don't take the transition durations from the global theme and need to be set imperatively as well.

Comment: @JamesHooper what do you mean by "imperatively"? How?

Comment: The comment was written about MUI 4 (I think), where you couldn't overwrite transitions globally. In that case, you would have needed to add the transition duration values directly to the components. In MUI 5, this is no longer necessary (but is still supported).